# Tomcat webpage not coming up

Tags: tomcat7

My tomcat default web page does not come up, please could someone tell me the reason following i have pasted the last 100 lines for catalina log

```
 Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/CursorableLinkedList$Cursor
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList.cursor(CursorableLinkedList.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:1488)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1700)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList$Cursor
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        ... 5 more

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that Tomcat cannot find a class from the [Apache Commons Pool library](http://commons.apache.org/pool/). Try adding the commons-pool jar under the WEB-INF/lib directory of your webapp.